# How to format html input so it starts from 0.00?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to format the HTML input element so it has default value 0.00 and when I enter some number it starts from the decimal place, for example, if I enter 6 it becomes 0.06, and if I continue changes typing it changes like 0.65, 6.54, 65.43, etc. I Am trying it now for a while and I didn't have any success. I found some answers that I should use step attribute but it doesn't do it. I also tried with react-format-number but didn't manage to do it.

1.HTML:

```
<input type="number" value="0.00" min="0.00" step="0.01"/>
```

2. React component:

```
    <NumberFormat
        {...other}
        getInputRef={inputRef}
        onValueChange={values => {
            onChange({
                target: {
                    value: values.value,
                    name: name
                },
            });
        }}
        thousandSeparator={","}
        decimalSeparator={"."}
        suffix=" EUR"
    />
```

Comment: Could you post some of the stuff you've tried, even if it doesn't work yet?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov i already accepted it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this kind of helps: (Note it's just an example)

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("0.00");
  const onChange = e => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    if (Number(v) === 0) {
      return setValue("0.00");
    }
    const arr = v.split(".");
    const afterDot1 = arr[0];
    const afterDot2 = arr[1].charAt(0);
    const afterDot = Number(`${afterDot1}${afterDot2}`);
    const beforeDot = arr[1].slice(1);
    const val = `${afterDot}.${
      beforeDot.length > 1 ? beforeDot : `${beforeDot}0`
    }`;
    setValue(val);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={onChange} type="number" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I didn't test all edge cases, but I'm sure you can get it **better** by regex or some other **mask** pattern.
see working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-fire-tis2e)

Answer (score 1):

You may store separate digits within your component's local state along with the digit place being currently entered.

With that you may simply modify corresponding digit by its place and pressed key.

You didn't describe what should happen when all the digit places are filled, so I left it rotating, but you may easily adjust that behavior according to your needs.

Below you may find quick and dirty live demo of that concept.

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM
      

const MyInput = () => {
  const [place, setPlace] = useState(2),
        [digits,setDigits] = useState([0,0,0]),
        onInput = d => {
          if(isNaN(d)) return
          setDigits((digits.splice(place,1,d),digits))
          setPlace(place ? place-1 : 2)
        }
  return (
    <input
      onKeyUp={e => onInput(e.key)}
      value={`${digits[0]}.${digits[1]}${digits[2]}`}
    ></input>
  )
}

render(
  <MyInput />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```